# Currently following the official Django tutorial, and I can't check if the length of list is equal to 0. Why?

Tags: python, django

Still on the official Django tutorial, and I am having a problem where I can't check if `len(Question.objects.all())` is equal to 0. I keep this getting this problem:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(Question.objects.all())' from 'len(Question.objects.all())'
```

and I can't see why this keeps happening.

polls/templates/polls/details.html

```
<h1> {{ question.question_text }} </h1>

{% if error_message %}<p> <strong> {{ error_message }} </strong> </p> {% endif %}
{% if len(Question.objects.all()) == 0 %}
        <p> There are no choices!  </p>
{% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"
                        value="{{ choice.id }}"/>
                        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
                        <br />
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
        </form>
{% endif %}
```

polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question

# Create your views here.

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Returns the last five published questions
        return Question.objects.filter(
                pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryqet(self):
        """ Exclude any unpublished questions. """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice!",
            })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return HttpResonseRedirect after POST success, prevents
        # data from being posted twice if someone hits the back button!
        return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id, )) )
```

Also, is this a good way of doing it? Or should I do something to the views.py, similar to how the IndexView filters out the 5 most recent articles. How can I do this to the DetailView? The len(Question.object.all()) works flawlessly in the shell, so I fail to see why it does not work when I use it in the django templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's definitely not working in django template. Even if it's working, it's a bad way to measure django queryset length. Because when you do `len()`, python would try to evaluate the list length by counting how many items are there. If you have a lot of results, you could be in trouble for the efficiency.

You should use ORM's api `exists()` for queryset:

```
if Question.objects.exists():
    # do something
```

Another problem you have is that you can't do the ORM operations in the template, because the model names are not available. You should ALMOST ALWAYS need to have as much logic as you can in views.py. So, create a variable called something like `questions = Question.objects.all()`, then do this in template:

```
{% if questions.exists %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Check django doc about the [common stuff that triggers the queryset evaluation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Also, to add the queryset to context in `DetailView`, [override function `get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).

Comment: Oh, thanks! It didn't work though, but that is because I realized I tried to check the amount of questions in the question list, when I was supposed to check for the choices that are connected to the question. I will figure this one out, though. Again, thanks